# route rule setting in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm learning about react
and I try to do route in app.tsx like :

```
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./components/protectedRoute";
import { HomePage, AboutPage, LoginPage, TestPage, MyApp1 } from "./pages/_pages";
import Layout from "./components/layout";

function App() {
  return (
        <>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<ProtectedRoute outlet={<Layout />} />}>
              <Route index element={<ProtectedRoute outlet={<HomePage />} />} />
              <Route path="about" element={<ProtectedRoute outlet={<AboutPage />} />} />
              <Route path="myapp1" element={<ProtectedRoute outlet={<MyApp1 />} />}>
                <Route path=":command" element={<ProtectedRoute outlet={<MyApp1 />} />}></Route>
                <Route path=":command/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute outlet={<MyApp1 />} />}></Route>
              </Route>
            </Route>
            <Route path="login" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/login" />} />
          </Routes>
        </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can create the type like :

```
export type AllowedCommands = "new" | "edit";

export type URLParams = {
  command: AllowedCommands;
  id?: string;
};
```

and myapp1 page :

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { URLParams } from "../Models/interfaces/AppPageParams";

const MyApp1 = () => {
  const pagePara = useParams<URLParams>();
  return (
    <AppLayout>
      <p>Command 2 : {pagePara.command}</p>
      {pagePara.id && <p>ID: {pagePara.id}</p>}
    </AppLayout>
  );
};
export default MyApp1;
```

for the http://localhost:3000/myapp1/*
any is good
but I want to make the rule where
command is only allow new or edit and if edit, it must provide id
so I expected

- http://localhost:3000/myapp1/ => will http://localhost:3000/myapp1
- http://localhost:3000/myapp1/new/ => will http://localhost:3000/myapp1/new (which pagePara.command = new)
- http://localhost:3000/myapp1/edit/1 => will http://localhost:3000/myapp1/edit/1 (which pagePara.command = edit and id =1)
- http://localhost:3000/myapp1/edit => will redirect http://localhost:3000/myapp1
- http://localhost:3000/myapp1/wrong => will redirect http://localhost:3000/myapp1

Can I know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

React-Router routes either match the path, or they do not match the path. A URL path like `"/myapp1/wrong"` will be matched by `"/myapp1/:command"` and the `MyApp1` component will be rendered. The `MyApp1` component will need to read the `command` value from the route params and implement its own validation.

Here's a simple validation.

```js
// Set of allowed commands
const AllowedCommands = new Set(["new", "edit"]);

// URL path segments are always string type
export type URLParams = {
  command?: string;
  id?: string;
};
```

```
const MyApp1 = () => {
  const { command, id } = useParams<URLParams>();

  // If command is truthy, validate it, otherwise allow UI to render
  return (command ? AllowedCommands.has(command) : true) ? (
    <AppLayout>
      <p>Command 2 : {command}</p>
      {id && <p>ID: {id}</p>}
    </AppLayout>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="*" replace />
  );
};
```

Since `MyApp1` isn't rendering an `Outlet` component there is no need to render any nested routes. Render a single route with the `:command` and `:id` parameters listed as optional (*available since v6.5.0*).

```
<Route
  path="myapp1/:command?/:id?"
  element={<ProtectedRoute outlet={<MyApp1 />} />}
/>
```

### Demo

[image: Edit route-rule-setting-in-react]

Comment: this example can solve, thank you
but if I have multi page , and I don't want every page to 
return (command ? AllowedCommands.has(command) : true) ? (
...}
how can I put it in common area ?

Comment: @CarrieKaski How many route paths do you have with a `"command"` path parameter? You could abstract the `command ? AllowedCommands.has(command) : true ....` logic into a wrapper/Higher Order Component for individual components, or into layout route component that wraps a group of routes. Can you edit the post to include an example use case you refer to?